# Javascript regex to detect end of sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect @username in a sentence. For this I use a simple `/\B@([\w]+)/ig`. This works well however this breaks when username contains a fullstop. For example something like, `@user.name`. So what would be the optimum regex to detect @username, where username could contain `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and a `.`.

Test sentence 1 : `Find @david in the database.` Here regex should match `david`

Test sentence 2 : `Find @david.name in the database.` Here regex should match `david.name`

Test sentence 3 : `Find who is @david. And tell him something.` Here regex should match `david` and not `david.`

Comment: Simply change `\w` (== `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) to what you actually want!

Comment: @Bergi he wants to match `.` when it's inside a name, but not when it's right after a name.

Comment: I think you can do this using a lookahead for space or the end of the string after the `.`

Comment: This is going to have a lot of edge cases, and it localizes poorly. What are you *really* trying to do, here? Why can't you replace usernames with "John," then run a boundary analysis tool on it?

Comment: Title does not match question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple regex:

```
/\B@\b([\w.]+)\b/g
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mE4cT4)

I've used `\w` because you used it in your regex. If you don't want underscore, then you can do:

```
/\B@\b([a-z\d.]+)\b/gi
```

Comment: Try test sentence 3 with that.

Comment: This seems like the best one. However I recommend `\B` in the front like `\B@\b([\w.]+)\b`. This will make sure that email addresses aren't picked up as username.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
/\B@([a-zA-Z0-9.]*[a-zA-Z0-9])/g
```

It allows the dot in the username, but not as the last character of it.

Comment: I'd use `[\w.]*\w` to keep with OP's logic.

Comment: @Sam: He didn't say he wanted to allow the underscore, which is matched by `\w`. If he did, it could of course be shortened to that.

Comment: Oh I missed that @Bergi, my bad. Take my +1 -- for OP, `\w` `===` `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: @Bergi The regexp he tried uses `\w`, which implies that underscores are allowed. His only issue is with `.`.

Comment: @Barmar "where username could contain `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and a `.`" -- I missed it too.

Comment: @Barmar: That's what my first comment on the question was aimed at, that his description doesn't match his regex. (And didn't read the last test sentence about the `.` at first).

Comment: This is mostly irrelevant. His question is about the logic for the `.`, the other characters are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your use cases, not sure if it will end up doing everything you want:

```
\B@((?:\w|\.(?=\S))+)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dA2eE3)

---

I tried to keep the logic fundamentally the same as yours, so essentially we match `\B@` and then capture `\w+`.  However, you also want to be able to match a `.` as long as it is not the end of the sentence (followed by a space).  So I put the `\w` in a non-capturing group and use alternation (`|`) to also allow for a `\.` if it is followed by a non-whitespace character (`(?=\S)`).  We then repeat this non-capturing group and capture the entire thing.